# Using jquery to make a div clickable and to run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i want to execute code when i click on a div.

So I have a function

```
function froth(){$("#area").load("test.html #enquiry1");}
```

I want to call this function when I click a div

```
 <div id="t1">Test</div>
```

So I try and use this code

```
 $('#t1').click(function(){
  froth();
  });
```

Nope it **doesnt** work.

***BUT***

I go to the HTML document and do this

```
<div id="t1" onclick="froth()">Test</div>
```

AND IT works **perfectly**.

So my question is, what am i doing wrong here? Why would it work when in the html doc and not work when i try and make it clickable with jquery?

Comment: Did you wrap your jQuery code in `$(document).ready`? Or `$(function() {...})`?

Comment: yeah its wrapped up good and tight

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to bind your click event **after** the rest of the DOM has loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#t1').on('click', function(){
        froth();
    });
});
```

You can see a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fdYV6/)

Comment: It doesnt work. I have had endless trouble with things not working in JS however as soon as you call the functions in the html it works...

Comment: Can you give us your entire JS file - it may be that your function `froth()` is out of the scope

Comment: i remove everything when i run into problems like this, just to make sure that nothings messing with the code...

Comment: Have you added jQuery to the page before the script?

Comment: no, i have only loaded the file above, and jquery library from google

Comment: I know it should work... i know it works in jsfiddle BUT it never seems to work on my computer

Comment: Upload your entire html file to paste bin

Comment: I copied it exactly as you wrote @jacktheripper and removed any scripts from my html file. It did not work, and i dont know why? :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30819/discussion-between-jacktheripper-and-ghozt)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '#t1', function() { 
 froth();
});
```